# Corrupted Excel file: what does this xml repair log say?

Tags: excel, xml, workfront-api

I have been downloading an Excel extract of the data from a work management service called Workfront, but somehow it started to spit out a corrupted file since a few months ago. If I open the Excel file, the Excel repairs it successfully, but this has become annoying. I wonder anyone can interpret the xml repair log. I have not touched the exportation setup so this must have something to do with the data?

this is the message it shows after repairing:

> Repaired Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part.

and this is the repair log:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><logFileName>error206080_03.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\Users\pb1101\Downloads\Task_Metrics_2021-08-13T12_45_37.xlsx'</summary><repairedParts><repairedPart xml:space="preserve">Repaired Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part. </repairedPart></repairedParts></recoveryLog>
```

Comment: Multiple reasons it seems, [here](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/106), [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/receives-error-while-exporting-supplier-profile-xlsx-format-replaced-part-xlworksheetssheet1xml-part-xml-error)